# Are protocols really the replacement of superclass?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I watched the Protocol-oriented programming video from WWDC15. After I saw this video, I got confused. Can anyone give me a relevant example illustrating this idea?

And more over protocol extension is the really replacement of operators overloading.

Comment: They don't mean a replacement in terms of syntax; they mean a replacement in terms of software design.  Apple is promoting use and adoption of protocols instead of creating base classes to inherit from.  With default implementations possible, a protocol can act much like a superclass.

Answer (score 1):

In dynamically typed languages (Ruby, Python, Javascript, etc) there is the concept of "duck typing", which essentially says it doesn't matter what the actual type of an object is, as long as it responds to certain methods. Rather than checking `instance_of?`, you can check `responds_to?` which is more relevant when you're using the check to determine if you can call a method anyway.

Protocols are simply a formal declaration of a duck type. Since you asked for an example (code is Ruby, which is dynamically typed — if you're unfamiliar with Ruby, just treat it as pseudocode and imagine everything typed as `id` and return values are `void`):

Imagine we're building a program to model transportation. We might have a few different modes of transportation:

```
class Bicycle
  def goto(x, y)
    # Implementation details
  end
end

class Car
  def goto(x, y)
    # Implementation details
  end
end

class Boat
  def goto(x, y)
    # Implementation details
  end
end

class Jetpack
  def goto(x, y)
    # Implementation details
  end
end
```

It would probably not make sense for all these classes to be subclasses of a `Vehicle` parent class, since a `Jetpack` would have very different properties and implementation details from a `Bicycle`. But notice that all these classes respond to the `goto(x, y)` method. It would be easy to create another class (like `Helicopter`, for example) that also responds to this method.

Now imagine we're using one of these classes:

```
class Person
  def travel(vehicle, destination)
    vehicle.goto(destination.x, destination.y)
  end
end
```

This code would work regardless of if `vehicle` is a `Bicycle`, `Boat`, or some other class defined in the future, because this code is calling a *protocol method* rather than a *type method*.

Answer (score 0):

A. The basic problem

Think of this situation:

You have instances of class `A` that interacts with other instances. `A`s have to know the API of the class the other instances are of. There are two ways to accomplish that:

- The other instances are of the (likely virtual) base class `B` and `A` knows the class `B` (via import or whatever). In such a case `A` can rely on `B`s capabilities.
- The other instances implements the protocol `B` and `A` knows the protocol `B` (via import or whatever). In such a case `A` can rely on `B`s capabilities, too.

The disadvantage of solution 1 is that `A` dictates the (base) class of the other instances. This can lead to a problems: First of all, the base class `B` cannot fit. Additionally maybe `B` should act as "Helper" for many classes, not only `A`. This would lead to multiple inheritance. No, no, no, nobody wants that.

Multi-protocol implementation is no problem.

B. Subclassing vs. delegating + protocol as pattern for specialization

In many cases you will find a base class `A` that should be specialized for some reasons, i. e. data access and providing. In a class based programming language you will find a (virtual) base class `A` and subclass it. Beside the problems discussed under A), you will find some others:

- Subclassing is white boxing: Subclasses know more than other classes.
- A base class contains many methods. What is the set of methods that are ought to be overwritten?

With protocols (and delegating) you can change that: Whenever a base class wants to be specialized, it puts the method into a protocol and "calls" an instance that implements the protocol (sends a message to the implementor of that protocol), when it needs specialized information. Another class can (optionally) implement this protocol and act as specialator.

This is called delegating, implemented using protocols and replaces subclassing.

C. More abstract

You can see that in a more abstract way:

- Protocols declares a set of methods, an API.
- Classes declares a set of methods, an API, *and* implement them.

So the difference between both is that classes are implementors.

So there is a rule of thumb: If you care about implementing something, use a subclass, because you can inherit much code from the base class. If you care about declaring an API, chose a protocol (and implement that in a class, not a subclass).

Comment: You are missing that Swift adds default implementations for protocols.  Thus, they can provide default functionality just by adopting them.

Comment: Yes, but this is language specific. You can do that in Objective-C with a combination of base class and protocol. However, I wanted to describe the generic advantage.

Comment: OK.  It's just that the question specifically refers to a WWDC video, in which Apple is extolling the virtues of protocol-oriented programming.  The video only applies to Swift, and only because of the default implementation feature.

Comment: The Q ist tagged with "objective-c swift". Si I assumed that the OP wants to know the language agnostic explanation. What is explained in the video is a very od technique, well-known in Objectve-C